# "Access is Denied" when consuming a web service over SOAP

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have created an .NET 3.5 web service application project that will be hosted under IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

I am able to consume the service from an ASP.NET application hosted on the same server and other server throughout our network without any issues.  When another employee tries to consumes the service using the SOAP protocol, they receive the following error:

> XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason is: Access
>   is denied.

The authentication configuration is set to Integrated Windows Authentication and the consumer will need to provide a service account's credentials when trying to consumer the service.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and do they know how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**

After speaking with my co-worker and vendor's customer service regarding consuming my web service, they revealed there are limitations within their INVOKE SOAP step.  According to the vendor:

> The Invoke SOAP object cannot interpret WSDL's containing In/Out
>   parameters if the WSDL message definition contains identical part
>   names for the input an output messages and identical data types.

The web service API contain a method and output parameter that were the same name.  If you look at the web service method in a browser, it had the following structure in the response:

```
<soap:Body>
    <MyServiceResponse>
        <MyServiceResponse>
            <property>...
```

The question now....Is this a common behavior while using the SOAP protocol or is this just limited to how vendor's product parses the SOAP message?

Comment: I understand that the other employee invoke it though another client app. If so, are you sure he is correctly pass the authentication credential within his code?

Comment: Think about what you just asked: is it common for WSDL (which describes a SOAP-based service) to be unparseable, or is it a problem with just one vendor?

Comment: @John Saunders - When I consume the service within a .NET application, I did not experience this problem.  I guess the only way to prove this would be to force the application to consume the service using the SOAP protocol.

Comment: When you consume the service within a .NET application, why do you think you're not using SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

This appears be a vendor-specific weakness, not a SOAP specification issue. They likely have a half-implemented SOAP stack.